# How do I know if I have a SATA compatible machine without opening the box?

Tags: sata

How do I know if I have a SATA compatible machine without opening the box? Or is the only way to open up the box and look at the connectors?

Comment: What OS is the machine running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check what PCI adapters are installed. The way how to do it depends on your operating system, e.g. *Device Manager* in windows or *lspci output* in linux. If your computer is a PC, you should check the BIOS messages during the boot process.

Comment: More specifically: Check what storage controllers the device managers list.

Answer (score 1):

Windows users: Get [System Information For Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/) (siw), it should display the important details of your computer.  At worst, it should help you figure out what mainboard you have, and you can then probably download a manual for it from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

use dmidecode.   Versions are available both under windows and linux

@Cian touche` for asking the correct question.

or use the absolutely wonderful SystemRescueCd livecd http://www.sysresccd.org

Comment: where can i find dmidecode?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm

Comment: dmidecode --type 8

then look for something like this:

 Internal Reference Designator: SATA CONTROLLER 0 - SATA0 (P30)